# Found this bug in my apartment in New York. Does anyone know what it is?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

It was around 2-4 mm in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just the second instar (nymph) of a [cockroach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_cockroach) (*Periplaneta americana*).

Compare with this image of the instars:

[image]

Source: http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/roaches/american_cockroach.htm

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for the picture though, it looks like what I found.